# Strip quote marks from string generated from input

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<h1 class="test">Hello</h1>

<form>
    <input class="rInput">
    <button id="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And script:

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var value = $('.rInput').val();
      console.log(value);
      $(".test").css('background-color', rInput);
    });
```

The above is my code, essentially what I want do is use the user's input to determinate what background color the  class will have, however the background-color does not seem to take the input as it contains "" (at least this is what I think the issue is, I may be wrong).

So my question is - How do I remove "" from my variable from a users input as seen above, or how do I fix the issue I have?

Comment: No, there are no extra quotes, that's just the console telling you that this is a string value. What value _did_ you enter into the input field? Most likely it was just invalid as a color ... like missing the leading `#` for hex notation, or sth like that.

Comment: You're storing the input value in the variable `value` but then you're passing `rInput` to the function. Are you getting an error in your console? e.g. `rInput is undefined`? You should be setting the background-color to `value`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks skyline, didnt even notice this..

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error that you can see if you debug your code. 
you stored the value that user input in a variable and aren't using this to set the color. 
Here is the solution

```js
 $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var value = $('.rInput').val();
      console.log(value);
      $(".test").css('background-color', value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="test">Hello</h1>

<form>
    <input class="rInput">
    <button id="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```